# MS ACCESS VBA: Me.Dirty = False OnTimer Event Reverts Edited Textbox Data

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

All,

First time asking a question here. Have found Stack Overflow to be very helpful with my MS VBA and MS ACCESS questions. Can't find anyone with quite the same problem, though. This issue is part of a fix for another problem, so I'll describe both if people are curious.

I have a form that multiple users (split db) use to fill out a request form. This form has many fields and two subsheets, so at times it can take a while for the users to fill out.

I have the form assign a new request number on the Form_BeforeInsert event, and it works well. It will add the number to the form the second someone begins entering data.

The first issue was that people were getting bizarre conflicts when filling out a request form at the same time. Data would transpose from one user's input and appear on another's. I hadn't seen the issue first hand, only getting second hand accounts.

My guess was that two users were filling out new requests simultaneously, and neither had saved the form until it had been filled out (so a long delay between adding a record and saving it). My solution was to force a save every ~5 seconds, done via the Form_OnTimer event. Here is my code for reference:

```
Private Sub Form_BeforeInsert(intCancel As Integer)
    Dim lngNewSampleNum As Long
    lngNewSampleNum = DMax("SAMPLE", "tbl_Table1") + 1

    'Assign default values
    SAMPLE = lngNewSampleNum
    DATE_INIT = Date$
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
    'Set timer on 5 sec interval
    Me.TimerInterval = 5000&
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Timer()
    'Save record (every 5 secs)
    If Me.Dirty Then
        Me.Dirty = False
    End If
End Sub
```

The issue I am having with the Me.Dirty=False event is that it will "forget" current text box data. To trigger, what I do is edit a field on the form, causing it to become dirty. Then, while the form is still dirty (the record indicator is a pencil), I type a few characters in a different field. Don't move the cursor, leave it in the field. Wait for the form to auto-save (record indicator changes to arrow). Type something, and what you previously written will be erased.

So this makes me suspect the Me.Dirty=false event isn't saving the current field changes, and in fact, will revert those changes (to blank) if you begin editing the field again. What this results in is users who begin typing, and then have the beginning of what they wrote disappear.

Does anyone have any suggestions to try? The only thing close that I found was on Allen Browne's website: http://allenbrowne.com/bug-01.html

I cannot post the DB as I work in R&D and it contains sensitive information. Using MS Access 2010 (Version: 14.0.7113.5005 32bit), and users are running MS Access Runtime 2010.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome Alex! Most people will not take the time to read this whole post, try to cut down future posts to only include relevant details (error messages, code, short background). Otherwise, it looks great!

Comment: Thanks for the tip.. I try to be thorough but sometimes things can get lengthy. I avoided using an AutoNumber this time because I used one for a request in the past and had issues when requests were deleted/misc quirks. I also had to migrate an older system into Access, so I needed to pick up the numbering where it left off.

Comment: Makes sense. Autonumbers are not meant to be continuous or contain any meaning other than uniqueness. There can be gaps in Autonumbers and that's OK. Are you using a version of access which supports data macros (i.e. from 2010 or greater). You can have the incrementing be managed by the table on a trigger. YOu then remove the burden of coding on your form.

Comment: I went with adding the code for default values into the New Request button procedure. I'm hoping that by adding the defaults and updating the recordset, that the table should save initially upon request record creation. That, hopefully, should propagate a new PK for the table and prevent someone from editing the same record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hope you find a satisfactory answer here!  I'm not posting my response in a comment because it wouldn't fit, but hopefully this provides some useful info.

When I make a form for data entry, I typically detach it from the table completely  - it sidesteps concurrency problems, I don't have to deal with some of the odder quirks of the Access interface and I can be sure everything is accomplished the way I want it.  So doing it purely through VBA kind of defeats a lot of the purpose of using Access and is frowned upon but for me it's much easier.

So that being said, if you had a single table you're uploading you could just the built in DAO recordset utilities (Feel free to skip this if you're already familair with them.)  So after detatching the form from a recordsource, you can ---

```
dim db as database
set db = currentdatabase

dim rst as recordset
set rst = db.openrecordset("myuploadtable")

dim frm as form
set frm = forms("mydatainputform")

with rst
   .addnew
   .fields("customername") = frm.txtCustomerName 'My textbox names
   .fields("purchaseamount") = frm.txtPurchaseAmount
   .update
end with
```

So if you are uploading to multiple tables, and need the ID to use as a foreign key in another table, you can retreive it by --(this would work directly under the code above)

```
rst.close
set rst = db.openrecordset("Select @@Identity")

dim myForeignKey as integer
myForeignKey = rst.fields(0)
rst.close
```

Another method to get the foreign key could be to select the MAX foreign key in that table (Almost guarenteed to get the right idea) or even better if the have a field you just uploaded that identified the user that submitted it, Select MAX id where theuser = 'Jim'

My understanding is this type of thing should be avoided and the standard access interface should be used whenever possible, I can think of a few reasons why that'd be the case (It's a uniform standard all access developers understand where your code might confuse them if it isn't written well) but I don't think there's any serious issue with detaching your forms from your recordsources.  I'd love to hear anyone else's input on this though

Good luck with your problem!

Comment: We will have to wait and see, but I am hoping something similar I went with solves the problem. I stuck all the code in the event procedure for the New request button. It manipulates the Me.RecordsetClone object, and sets the new bookmark for the form. I migrated my default values into that function (SAMPLE, DATE_INIT, etc.) and got rid of the BeforeInsert event.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is where you get your key -- nothing to prevent TWO users from getting the same key because you don't update the recordset at this point. I recommend you use code that will grab & confirm YOU have the key (i.e. can you insert into the key table along with either your workstation name or user name?)

Comment: I put some code to create a new record, assign defaults, and update the recordset all in the New Request button procedure. Hopefully this writes changes to the table and prevents users from getting the same PK.